# How to create a query that returns data grouped by date without repetition in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, collections

I have a table `scans` in my db, where a user's scan activity is recorded and a user can have multiple activities in a day. I am looking for the best way to fetch the sum of all the scans for a particular user over a period of days.

I have tried the following in my code, but I guess I'm missing something as I would like to aggregate the scans for a user that was made same day.

```
 DB::table('scans')->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total, scanner, created_at'))->where('scanner', 'Jon Snow')->groupBy('created_at')->get()
=> Illuminate\Support\Collection {#3313
     all: [
       {#3304
         +"total": 1,
         +"scanner": "Jon Snow",
         +"created_at": "2020-07-26 19:43:58",
       },
       {#3321
         +"total": 1,
         +"scanner": "Jon Snow",
         +"created_at": "2020-07-26 19:32:40",
       },
       {#3327
         +"total": 1,
         +"scanner": "Jon Snow",
         +"created_at": "2020-07-28 19:44:18",
       },
       {#3323
         +"total": 1,
         +"scanner": "Jon Snow",
         +"created_at": "2020-07-28 20:30:30",
       },
```

So instead of this:

```
       {#3304
         +"total": 1,
         +"scanner": "Jon Snow",
         +"created_at": "2020-07-26 19:32:58",
       },
       {#3321
         +"total": 1,
         +"scanner": "Jon Snow",
         +"created_at": "2020-07-26 19:43:40",
       },
```

I would have this:

```
       {#3304
         +"total": 2,
         +"scanner": "Jon Snow",
         +"created_at": "2020-07-26",
       },
       {#3304
         +"total": 5,
         +"scanner": "Jon Snow",
         +"created_at": "2020-07-28",
       },
```

Comment: You want to group by date, but in your example you've grouped the two entries with different dates, one is `2020-07-26` and the other is `2020-07-27` . Is the example wrong, or there's something missing in the statement?

Comment: they are not a repetition, they have different dates

Comment: sorry, i see my mistake now. I've corrected that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem:**

At the moment you are doing **groupBy(created_at)**. Since almost all Scans have a diffrent datetime the groupBy will not work as excpected.

---

**Solutions:**

If I understood correctly, you want the groupBy by date of created_at without the time. For that you will have to select only the date part of your datetime column. There are 2 ways to do this:

```
DB::raw('count(*) as total, DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y-%m-%d") as someDate, scanner')
->where('scanner', 'Jon Snow')
->groupBy('someDate')
->get()
```

**@edit**

You could also do `DATE(created_at) as someDate`

---

**Example:**

I have 4 Users inserted into my Database:

- 2 have created_at => '2020-05-05 10:10:10'
- 2 have created_at => '2020-10-10 10:10:10'

Result:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1945
  #items: array:2 [
    0 => {#1952
      +"count": 2
      +"new_date": "2020-05-05"
    }
    1 => {#2092
      +"count": 2
      +"new_date": "2020-10-10"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: if all of the scanns are created at the same date, otherwise you will get multiple arrays. I tested it with my Users and it seems to work like intended

Comment: Thank you @Aless55 but this aggregates all scans over a period of days and returns them as one result, instead i would want it to return scans for each day as one result with aggregated counts.

Comment: @goodhand, I don't understand, for me it returns the aggregation for each day seperately in an array, you can see my example how the result looks like.

Comment: Update: oh yes, it worked. I had an error where I was grouping by `scanner` instead of `date`. Thank you @Aless55

Comment: @goodhand ah now it makes sense :D glad it works now